# QMAIL Server replied: 451 qq trouble creating files in queue (#4.3.0)

Tags: email, qmail

Getting the above error when I send and email using both telnet interface and the web interface. I am using qmail. Can someone pls help.

This is what i get when I run qmailctl stat

```
>[root@pristine qmail-send]# qmailctl stat 
/service/qmail-send: up (pid 20193) 2952 seconds
/service/qmail-send/log: up (pid 20195) 2952 seconds
/service/qmail-smtpd: up (pid 20199) 2952 seconds
/service/qmail-smtpd/log: up (pid 7692) 1 seconds
/service/qmail-pop3d: up (pid 20203) 2952 seconds
/service/qmail-pop3d/log: up (pid 7693) 1 seconds
messages in queue: 0
messages in queue but not yet preprocessed: 0
```

After running ps aux on the smtp processes I got the following

```
 ps aux | grep -i qmail
root      5606  0.0  0.0  1344  224 pts/1    S    13:24   0:00 readproctitle service errors: ...ure?supervise: fatal: unable to acquire qmail-pop3d/supervise/lock: temporary failure?supervise: fatal: unable to acquire log/supervise/lock: temporary failure?supervise: fatal: unable to acquire qmail-smtpd/supervise/lock:
root      5674  0.0  0.0  1344  224 pts/1    S    13:24   0:00 readproctitle service errors: ...ry failure?supervise: fatal: unable to acquire qmail-pop3d/supervise/lock: temporary failure?supervise: fatal: unable to acquire log/supervise/lock: temporary failure?supervise: fatal: unable to acquire log/supervise/lock: t
root      5679  0.0  0.0  1352  268 pts/1    S    13:25   0:00 supervise qmail-send
root      5689  0.0  0.0  1352  268 ?        S    13:25   0:00 supervise qmail-pop3d
root      5691  0.0  0.0  1352  264 ?        S    13:25   0:00 supervise qmail-smtpd
root     11432  0.0  0.0  1608  456 pts/1    S    13:36   0:00 grep -i qmail
root     11600  0.0  0.0  1372  284 ?        S    May15   0:00 tcpserver -H -R -v -c100 0 110 qmail-popup mail.pristine.gm /home/vpopmail/bin/vchkpw qmail-pop3d Maildir
vpopmail 11601  0.0  0.0  1544  456 ?        S    May15   0:00 /usr/local/bin/tcpserver -v -R -l mail.pristine.gm -x /etc/tcp.smtp.cdb -c 30 -u 510 -g 505 0 smtp /var/qmail/bin/qmail-smtpd mail.pristine.gm /home/vpopmail/bin/vchkpw /usr/bin/true
qmaill   11615  0.0  0.0  1496  328 ?        S    May15   2:01 multilog t s100000 n20 /var/log/qmail/qmail-pop3d
```

Comment: what's in the log (smtpd if you separate your logs)? you may also have better luck over at superuser.com (SO sister site, part of the SE network).

Comment: The SMTP logs has not been logging. That is another strange problem too

Comment: Thank you I posted the question at superuser.com

Comment: link to @asembereng question: http://superuser.com/questions/670292/qmail-server-replied-451-qq-trouble-creating-files-in-queue-4-3-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the queue using queue-repair tool. That fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

readproctitle shows that different supervise processes cannot acquire lock.
This might indicate a full or otherwise not-writable filesystem.

What's the output of `df` and `df -i`?

Perhaps it's as simple as just to make some free space...